# Given a string, how to generate all possible arrays of substrings where each substring contains no more than N, but not less than M chars?

Tags: javascript, string, algorithm

I have a string `str` and two positive integers, `M` and `N`, where `M` can be less than or equal to `N`. All I want is to split the string so that each part contains no more than `N` chars, but not less than `M` chars (assuming that the length of the string is greater than `M`; if it is not greater than `N`, we may assume that `N` is equal to the length of the string). For example, if `M=1`, `N=3` and my string is `"aabcde"`, the result should be

```
var str = "aabcde";
var result = [
["a", "a", "b", "cde"],
["a", "ab", "cde"],
["aa", "b", "cde"],
//...
["aab", "cde"],
["aab", "cd", "e"],
["aab", "c", "de"],
["aab", "c", "d", "e"]  
]
```

What is the efficient way to solve this, avoiding unnecessary intermediate subarrays? I don't want to generate all possible combinations, and then delete each subarray if it contains at least one substring with inacceptable length. Is there another way, without unnecessary computations?

Comment: I tried to apply `result[k].filter(function (i) {return !(i.length <= M || i.length >= N);})` dynamically, but that does not solve the problem.

Comment: You should at least show the code for your inefficient solution, so that you can think of ways to optimize from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This effectively boils down to generating restricted [integer compositions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_(combinatorics)) with parts between two values `M` and `N`. It is a simple matter to generate such compositions recursively.

I also noticed in your example for `"aabcde", M=1, N=3"` that your array lengths were all less than or equal to `4` in length, so I also included an optional parameter to restrict the number of parts in each composition.

```
function* restrictedCompositions(n, a, b, k = n) {
    if (!(0 < a && a <= b && b <= n && 0 < k && k <= n)) {
        throw "invalid arguments";
    }

    let C = [];

    function* recGen(m, r) {
        if (m == 0) {
            yield C; // client must copy if they wish to store value for later
        }
        else {
            let y = Math.min(b, m);
            let x = Math.max(a, m - y*(r - 1));

            for (let v = x; v <= y; v++) {
                C.push(v);
                yield* recGen(m - v, r - 1);
                C.pop();
            }
        }   
    }

    yield* recGen(n, k);
}

function* generateChoppedStrings(str, M, N, K = str.length) {
    for (let composition of restrictedCompositions(str.length, M, N, K)) {
        let chopped = [];
        let i = 0;

        for (let part of composition) {
            let j = i + part;
            chopped.push(str.slice(i, j));
            i = j;
        }

        yield chopped;
    }
}

function chopString(str, M, N, K = str.length) {
    for (let chopped of generateChoppedStrings(str, M, N, K)) {
        console.log(chopped);
    }
}

chopString("aabcde", 1, 3, 4);
```

Output:

```
["a", "a", "b", "cde"]
["a", "a", "bc", "de"]
["a", "a", "bcd", "e"]
["a", "ab", "c", "de"]
["a", "ab", "cd", "e"]
["a", "ab", "cde"]
["a", "abc", "d", "e"]
["a", "abc", "de"]
["aa", "b", "c", "de"]
["aa", "b", "cd", "e"]
["aa", "b", "cde"]
["aa", "bc", "d", "e"]
["aa", "bc", "de"]
["aa", "bcd", "e"]
["aab", "c", "d", "e"]
["aab", "c", "de"]
["aab", "cd", "e"]
["aab", "cde"]
```

Comment: Thanks. I have two notes: 1. Why does this log one `undefined` at the end? 2. "your array lengths were all less than or equal to 4 in length" — No. All other subarrays are hidden behind the `//...` comment.

Comment: @lyricallywicked 1. I'm not sure. Maybe your console is printing the return value of `chopString` (which there is none) at the end. You can create a list of all results using `Array.from(generateChoppedStrings(...))` instead of printing them. 2. No problem, you can always just leave off the 4th argument when calling the function(s) and it'll generate all possible results.

Answer (score 1):

You can generate all possible arrays using recursion. Get all possible starting substrings (of length M..N) and call the next recursion level for the rest of string.

This approach don't generate excessive (bad) subarrays (but can generate the same sets from string tail some times)

Note that you can work both with substrings, and with integer array of split positions, and make real substrings in the last step of recursion.

Simple Delphi example:

```
procedure SplitStr(s, Reslt: string; LMin, LMax: Integer);
var
  i, Len: Integer;
  left, right: string;
begin
  Len := Length(s);
  if Len = 0 then
    Memo1.Lines.Add(Reslt)
  else
    for i := LMin to Min(LMax, Len) do begin
      left := LeftStr(s, i);
      right := RightStr(s, Len - i);
      SplitStr(right, Reslt + left + '| ' , LMin, LMax);
    end;
end;

begin
  SplitStr('aabcde', '', 1, 3);
```

outputs

```
a| a| b| c| d| e| 
a| a| b| c| de| 
a| a| b| cd| e| 
a| a| b| cde| 
a| a| bc| d| e| 
a| a| bc| de| 
a| a| bcd| e| 
a| ab| c| d| e| 
a| ab| c| de| 
a| ab| cd| e| 
a| ab| cde| 
a| abc| d| e| 
a| abc| de| 
aa| b| c| d| e| 
aa| b| c| de| 
aa| b| cd| e| 
aa| b| cde| 
aa| bc| d| e| 
aa| bc| de| 
aa| bcd| e| 
aab| c| d| e| 
aab| c| de| 
aab| cd| e| 
aab| cde|
```